# Wordpress, search in post's categories description too (OR term_taxonomy.description LIKE %A%)

Tags: wordpress, search, categories, taxonomy-terms

I'm struggling with finding a simple way for wordpress search to also search in post's categories description.
I found few topics but no real anwser.

The thing is, that the user might be typing what they search for + category name too (for example, "Mario Nintendo 64", where "Nintendo 64" is the category name. As of right now, it would return no results, which doesn't feel right).

I need to search in term_taxonomy.description, as categories have aliases, which I enter in this field (for instance: "Nintendo 64, N64 etc...")

Here what I came up with.

```
function custom_posts_join ($a) {
    global $wpdb;
    return $a . " INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id) 
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id) ";
}

function custom_posts_where ($a) {
    global $wpdb;
    return $a . " AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'";
}

add_filter('posts_join', custom_posts_join );
add_filter('posts_where', custom_posts_where );
```

Still, I need to be able to integrate `OR (term_taxonomy.description LIKE '%A%')`in the search
as of right now the sql request only search for

```
(posts.post_title LIKE '%A%') 
OR (posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%A%') 
OR (posts.post_content LIKE '%A%')
```

Also, would it be possible to add DISTINCT, so it does not return the same post multiple times, based on the fact that posts can belong to multiple categories.

I really don't know if I'm on the right path here, but I'm stuck.
Also I am wondering how heavy, what may have seemed like a little adjustment, this will turn out to be on the server?
I haven't been developping for years, and now I'm back to it, and I'm not sure if this will make the search too heavy. Is INNER JOIN the best way?

Is there another way I could handle the search to search in the categories description of the posts.

Comment: Have you tried running a direct SQL query or do you need to use the WP_Query?

Comment: I tried running a direct SQL, and it works. But yeah, I'm trying to integrate my change through filters, so I don't mess up too much with the wordpress code. I just need to be able to add this small condition through filters 'OR (term_taxonomy.description LIKE '%s%')'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of research, I finally made progress, and everything works perfectly!

Here what it looks like now:

```
function custom_posts_join ( $join ) {
    global $wpdb;
    if ( is_search() ) {
        $join .= " INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id) 
        INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id) ";
    }
    return $join;
}    

function custom_posts_where ( $where ) {
    global $wpdb;
    if ( is_search() ) {
        $where = preg_replace(
                "/\(\s*".$wpdb->posts.".post_title\s+LIKE\s*(\'[^\']+\')\s*\)/",
                "(".$wpdb->posts.".post_title LIKE $1) OR (".$wpdb->term_taxonomy.".description LIKE $1)", $a );
        $where .= " AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy='category'";
    }
    return $where;
}
add_filter('posts_join', custom_posts_join );
add_filter('posts_where', custom_posts_where );
```

And to add DISTINCT:

```
function custom_posts_distinct ( $distinct ) {
    global $wpdb;
    if ( is_search() ) {
        return "DISTINCT";
    }
    return $distinct;
}
add_filter( 'posts_distinct', 'custom_posts_distinct' );
```

**Still, how about performance, doing 2 INNER JOIN every research?**

Anyway, here is a full solution, I hope this will help someone.